# Can someone expain to me what's going on (binomial coefficient)?

Tags: binomial-coefficients, zeta-functions, cauchy-product

I'm watching [this proof](https://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PL32446FDD4DA932C9&v=XHQ0OzqTjd0) for $\zeta(2n)$ on YouTube.

This is what I can understand so far:

$${s\over e^{s} -1} = \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} {\beta_n\over n!} s^n$$

Where $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} {\beta_n\over n!} s^n$ is meant to represent a **Taylor Series** for ${s\over e^{s} -1}$.

We then re-wrote ${e^{s} -1}$ as its Taylor Series like so:

$${s\over \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} {1\over n!} s^n} = \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} {\beta_n\over n!} s^n$$

Then just rearranged like so:

$${s =\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} {\beta_n\over n!} s^n \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} {1\over n!} s^n}$$

We then diveded both sides by $s$ like so:

$${1 =\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} {\beta_n\over n!} s^n \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} {1\over n!} s^{n-1}}$$

We then made $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} {1\over n!} s^{n-1}$ start at $n=0$:

$${1 =\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} {\beta_n\over n!} s^n \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} {1\over (n+1)!} s^{n}}$$

Then using **Cauchy's Proof** for multiplying two power series, we can equate the previous sums to:

$$1= \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \sum^{n}_{\mu =0} {\beta_{\mu}\over \mu!} {1\over (n- \mu + 1)!} s^n$$

If we multyply by $(n+1)!$ we then get:

$${\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \sum^{n}_{\mu =0} {\beta_{\mu}\over \mu!} {(n+1)! \over (n- \mu + 1)!} s^n} $$

Which equals:

$${\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \sum^{n}_{\mu =0} {(n+1)! \over \mu! (n- \mu + 1)!} \beta_{\mu} s^n} $$

This then equal to:

$${\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \sum^{n}_{\mu =0} {{n+1}\choose \mu} \beta_{\mu} s^n} $$

We can then divide by $(n+1)!$ and get:

$$1 = {\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} {1\over (n+1)!} \sum^{n}_{\mu =0} {{n+1}\choose \mu} \beta_{\mu} s^n} $$

Now here is where I'm confused. The lecturer who made the video said something about the coefficient in ${{n+1}\choose \mu} {\beta_{\mu} s^n}$ is always $0$.

This last statement lost me completely.

Can someone explain please?

Comment: Compare the coefficients of $s^n$ on the two sides of the equation.

Comment: @MohsenShahriari - Ohh wow. I just got it haha.

Comment: @MohsenShahriari - The coefficient for $s^n$ on the left hand side is 0 seeing as we only have 1 and no $s^n$ term.